# php как получить неизвестную куку

Tags: php

Есть кука jv_client_id_AhRD2O7QUR

Все что после jv_client_id_ случайная комбинация, как получить куку не смотря на случайную комбинацию? Может есть какое то регулярное выражение?

Comment: конечно, сканируете массив с куками по ключу и выбираете при помощи например `substr ( $key , 0, strlen("jv_client_id_" )) == "jv_client_id_")`

Comment: если что не получится, приходите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отфильтровать куки с помощью `array_filter` определяя вхождение подстроки "jv_client_id_" с помощью `strpos`.
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a680ed23abf40de435c73338164ec3564fb01ea3

Код:

```
<?php

$_COOKIE['jv_client_id_AhRD2O7QUR'] = 1;
$_COOKIE['jv_client_id_AhRD2O7QUB'] = 2;
$_COOKIE['user'] = 3;
$_COOKIE['jv_client_id_AhRD2O7QUE'] = 4;

$jv_client_id = array_filter($_COOKIE, function($key){
   return (strpos($key,'jv_client_id_') !== false);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

print_r($jv_client_id);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [jv_client_id_AhRD2O7QUR] => 1
    [jv_client_id_AhRD2O7QUB] => 2
    [jv_client_id_AhRD2O7QUE] => 4
)
```

Comment: только `(strpos($key,'jv_client_id_') === 0);`  текст вроде как в начале строки должен быть, а не в любом месте